# React-Leaflet: Set marker when clicking on the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am developing a React app on my Ubuntu 20.4 VM machine in a chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) browser.

I have created the following app:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-map-with-marker-forked-vtq00e?file=/Map.js

I am trying to set a marker when clicking on the map using the following:

In my `Map.js` I set the click event:

```
  return (
    <div id="map" style={style}>
      <MapContainer
        // center={[40.0151, -105.2921]}
        center={[40.7579747, -73.9877313]}
        // @ts-ignore
        onClick={addMarker}
        zoom={15}
        style={{ height: "90%" }}
        // @ts-ignore
        onZoomEnd={console.log}
      >
```

The following function should then set the marker:

```
function addMarker(e) {
  console.log("marker \n");

  const { markers } = this.state;
  markers.pop();
  markers.push(e.latlng);
  this.setState({ markers });
}
```

However, when I click on the map nothing is happening. I also do not get a console output.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason why TypeScript tells you that `onClick` and `onZoomEnd` props are not available on `<MapContainer>` component from React Leaflet: the latter was introduced in React Leaflet version 3, and map events should now be used through the `useMapEvents` hook, as you already have tried in some of your attempts as can be seen in your CodeSandbox.

What may not be obvious with the `useMapEvents` hook, is that it must be used in a custom component that will be a **child** (descendant) of your MapContainer. See e.g. [Trying to apply zoom on click with react-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069837/trying-to-apply-zoom-on-click-with-react-leaflet/71070344#71070344)

Furthermore, `this.setState` is typical of **class-based** React components, whereas in your CodeSandbox you use functional components. Note that hooks can only be used in functional React components.